instances of pm2 crashes during error "write EPIPE" one after another
pm2 version 5.3.1, application in cluster mode, 7 instance Periodically after an error:
Error: write EPIPE
    at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:87:16)

down one after another 2-3, sometime everything instances
pm2 App name: id: disconnected exited with code 0

After such an error, crashes do not always occur, more often the error simply appears in the console and in full:
Error: write EPIPE
    at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:87:16) {
  errno: 'EPIPE',
  code: 'EPIPE',
  syscall: 'write'
}

In this case, there is no crash and the error goes to the handler https.on('clientError', () => ...); https.on('error', () => ...);
The load on the server was not high, it was much higher and without crashes. But it should be noted that this starts abruptly in the middle of the day and ends abruptly at the end.
Please tell me what could be wrong, what should I do?
reboot server, restart, clear, update pm2

My recommendation: Try to not use any callbacks. If an API uses callbacks (e.g. https), wrap it into promises as tightly as you can, to limit exposure to asynchronous errors that crash your process - or use a different API that uses promises out of the box (e.g. fetch).
